# Swift : Avatar image is mandatory in swift code

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, swift2, uialertview

By default "no-profile-image" is set to imageview, User should upload the profile picture mandatory while registration, otherwise user should not allow to navigate to next screen.Any help is appreciable.
Here is my code

```
lazy var profileLogo:UIImageView = {
        let profileLogo = UIComponentFactory.appImageView(UIImage(named: "no-profile-image")!, contentMode: .ScaleToFill, cornerRadius: LayoutService.width(15))
        profileLogo.userInteractionEnabled = false
        return profileLogo
    }()
 func nextButtonPressed() {
let noImage = UIImage(named: "no-profile-image")
            if self.mainView.profileLogo.image == nil && self.mainView.profileLogo.image == noImage{
                displayAlert("", message: "profile picture is mandatory, please upload it")
}
 }
```